# How do I stop checkbox from pasting in Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I create a picture of a range and paste it into Outlook. The code works but I added a checkbox that is located in the range that I do NOT want to paste into Outlook.

I used `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False`. It works sometimes and other times it doesn't. When I step through the code I get the same inconsistent results.

```vb
Public Sub ScreenShotResults4_with_Current()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("B9:N37")
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    'Sheets("Summary").Branch_ChkBox.Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
        
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
        
    'strbody = "See production data for most recent 3 months.  "
        
    With Email
        .To = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B21").Value
        .Subject = "12 Month LO Production Lookback for " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B21").Value & " (" & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B23").Value & "- " & Worksheets("Summary").Range("B35").Value & ")"
        '.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
        .Display
            
        wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False
        'if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
        With wdDoc.Content
            '--- paste the range image first, because it overwrites
            '    everything in the document
            ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False
            .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
            .InlineShapes(1).Height = 350
        
            '--- now add our greeting at the start of the email
            .InsertBefore "See 12 month production data and current pipeline. " & vbCr & vbCr
                                   
            '--- finally add our sign off after the image
            .InsertAfter vbCr & _
              "Thank you" & vbCr & vbCr
        End With
        
        .Display
    End With
        
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
        
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `ActiveSheet`? That's most likely the problem. Instead, qualify it with a worksheet variable that you set to the one you want.

Comment: I tried changing to Sheets("Summary").CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by putting the same part of the code buy at the top right under the declarations
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False